# Multiprocess a function in python that got multiple parameters

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-2.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing library in python but I met some difficulties:

```
def request_solr(limit=10, offset=10):
    # build my facets here using limit and offset
    # request solr
    return response.json()

def get_list_event_per_user_per_mpm(limit=100):
    nb_unique_user = get_unique_user()
    print "Unique user: ", nb_unique_user
    processor_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    offset = range(0, nb_unique_user, limit)
    list_event_per_user = processor_pool.map(request_solr(limit), offset)
    return list_event_per_user
```

I'm not sure how to pass the second parameters into the function. How can I make it work. I've got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lambda for this. The way you're doing it right now, it's trying to map the result of `request_solr` as a function with `offset` as the argument.

This should do the trick.

```
processor_pool.map(lambda x: request_solr(limit, x), offset)
```

Note, this only works in 3.x. In 2.x you need to create a function object. For example:

```
class RequestSolrCaller:
    def __init__(self, limit)
        self.limit = limit
    def __call__(self, offset)
        return request_solr(self.limit, offset)

processor_pool.map(RequestSolrCaller(limit), offset)
```

Comment: I've got the following error: PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Comment: @mel Ah, you must be on 2.x. This only works in 3.x, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you see that error because you are calling the function *before* passing it to multiprocessing.

I suggest you use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) in combination with [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
import itertools as it

# rest of your code

processor_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
offset = range(0, nb_unique_user, limit)
list_event_per_user = processor_pool.starmap(request_solr, zip(it.repeat(limit), offset))
```

Starmap will call your function expanding the pair of values into two arguments. The `repeat(limit)` simply produces an iterable that has all elements equal to `limit`.

This can work for any number of arguments:

```
def my_function(a, b, c, d, e):
    return a+b+c+d+e

pool = Pool()
pool.starmap(my_function, [(1,2,3,4,5)])   # calls my_function(1,2,3,4,5)
```

---

Since you are using an old version of python you have to work around this by either modifying your function or using a wrapper function:

```
def wrapper(arguments):
    return request_solr(*arguments)

# later:

pool.map(wrapper, zip(repeat(limit), offset))
```

Comment: I've got the following error: AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'starmap'

Comment: @mel That's because you are using an ancient version of python. I will write an alternative.

Comment: @mel Someone already did that. Anyway you should not *replace* the python tag but *add* the version-specific tag. So you should have both python and python2.x/2.7. Why? For your benefit: not so many people follow the python2.7 tag, so by removing it you are losing audience. Also a lot of problems that seem version specific turn out to have portable solutions (not in this case I'm afraid).

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a generator to produce the keywords. This is the content a my simple_multiproc.py.

**Note the important of having request_solr at level module.**

```
import multiprocessing

MAX=5

def _get_pool_args(**kw):
    for _ in range(MAX):
        r = {"limit": 10, "offset": 10}
        r.update(kw)
        yield r


def request_solr(limit=10, offset=10):
    # build my facets here using limit and offset
    # request solr
    print(locals())
    response.json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX)
    pool.map(request_solr, _get_pool_args())
```